# Domain attached computer - Allow account selection at logon?

Tags: windows-7, login, windows-domain

(Windows 7, x64)
When not attached to a domain, Windows will show a list of accounts available to log into (of which you can use various methods to show or hide) on the GINA. However, once joined to a domain this all goes away and you need to type both username and password. Only once logged in can you see other accounts that may be logged in, but once they're logged out of course they disappear from the login screen.

Is there a way to specify a list of accounts to log into when attached by a domain? I would imagine just listing the accounts that have logged on previously, with the "Switch Account" button providing the means to specify a new user to "Add" to the machine.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible :(

Comment: Yeah I'm fairly certain as well. I got far enough down the rabbit hole that it looks like I would need to implement my own GINA interface, and I probably don't have time for that...

Comment: If it is possible, I think it would be something in the domain security settings.